# Trajectory of a projectile in a three dimensional space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, simulations, projectile, coordinate-systems

$g$: the gravitational acceleration—usually taken to be $9.81\:\mathrm{m/s^2}$ near the Earth's surface

$θ$: the angle at which the projectile is launched

$v$: the speed at which the projectile is launched

$y_0$: the initial height of the projectile

$d$: the total horizontal distance travelled by the projectile

The height $y$ of the projectile at distance $x$ is given by
[image: eq]

However I'm writing a 3D game engine and would like to find out how to make that equation work in a three dimensional space $x,y,z$.

Comment: Anyone who solves these kinds of problems *kisses their hands* because it can be done in 2 dimensions only. Why add one that's not needed?

Comment: Well I'm writing some code for things such as throwing grenades, and I need to calculate their trajectories and make them go along those trajectories and such, and going through the wikipedia page of projectile trajectories I thought of this being relevant information for my purpose, am I wrong?

Comment: You should be able to use two dimensions only. Adding a third needlessly complicates things (a little). I can see one reason for doing it but you need to explain better *why you* think your code needs it.

Comment: Well I guess I'll go and try to tackle with this with myself, I just thought of a few things that might solve this, thanks though

Comment: Have a look at this, see if it's useful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/212941/

Comment: I have to agree with Gert. As a game engine designer you should know how to do a rotation around a coordinate axis, I believe? That's all there is to it.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I can see how you might want to it in $x,y,z$ if multiple projectiles are fired from multiple positions/weapon systems to multiple targets, like in a game. It's not hard, just a lot of tedious algebra. OP gives no indication that that is his purpose though.

Comment: @CuriousOne not really a game engine designer, doing this as a hobby really.

Comment: @Gert: We had a couple of questions about Newtonian mechanics for game engine design since I joined a while ago. I think the tougher stuff is centered around calculating the dynamics of rigid bodies including rotation. In comparison a simple decomposition of the initial velocity vector and a rotation seems outright trivial. I think the OP should be able to handle that.

Comment: @CuriousOne: probably. I'm not a mind reader, though. ;-) If he gets stuck I'll offer my *paid* services!

Comment: I think I have to eat my previous comment to Gert now. :-). OK, basically, what he is telling you is that you should look at the problem as happening in two dimensions. Do you know how to rewrite the problem in cylindrical coordinates? In cylindrical coordinates the $\varphi$ component of the motion is constant, i.e. the parabola is the solution in $r$ and $z$ coordinates and all you have to do is two transform, one to get the initial $v_r$, $v_z$ and $v_\varphi,$ from the initial velocity vector, and then an inverse transform to get back to Euclidean coordinates.

Comment: @Gert: Judging by the quality and quantity of the questions it seems to me that there is a need for a "Newtonian physics for game designers" textbook. Maybe there are good ones out there, but I never cared to look. If there isn't, this might be the opportunity for someone to make a buck writing one. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I'd definitely buy that.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I think you're on to something! Care for a JV? Do I really have to brush up on cylindrical coordinates, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three dimensions are no different than two. If $y$ is the vertical direction and you have worked out the equations for $y$ and $x$, you can apply the same equations with $z$ substituted in for $x$.

This is because physics is isotropic - the same in all directions. Gravity breaks the isotropy for the vertical dimension, but there is no physical difference between $x$ and $z$ so they are interchangeable.

This is not perfectly true on Earth because the rotation axis of Earth breaks the symmetry between $x$ and $z$, so there are Coriolis forces that are different in the $x$ and $z$ directions, but these are minor for everyday circumstances.